# giving same css property at CSS-Grid when using html section tag

Tags: html, css, properties, css-grid

I know:

At CSS-Grid with html dives, giving same css property (`border-radius: 5px;` for example) to all div's in one line [see this example](https://codepen.io/ariebl/pen/KRZRvV?editors=1100)

and I know:

at CSS-Grid with html section to give css property, `border-radius: 5px;` to each block [see here](https://codepen.io/ariebl/pen/JvWQaq)

My question is:

How can I type the "border-radius: 5px", once and that will affects all the blocks inside the section [here](https://codepen.io/ariebl/pen/JvWQaq)?

Note, I need to use the html section in order to use CSS Grid

Comment: Can you please clarify. Is your aim to only type the "border-radius: 5px", once and that it affects all the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you wish to have only 1 line of (border-radius: 5px;) in your CSS file and that the border-radius affects all content inside of section.

Attached you find a code snippet with a solution.
You basically need to first define each grid-area. As second step you can define the border-radius with one line.

```css
#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "head head"
                       "nav  main"
                       "nav  foot";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#page > header {grid-area: head; background-color: #8ca0ff;}
#page > nav {grid-area: nav; background-color: #ffa08c;}
#page > main {grid-area: main; background-color: #ffff64;}
#page > footer {grid-area: foot; background-color: #8cffa0;}


#page > header,
#page > nav,
#page > main,
#page > footer {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="page">
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <main>Main area</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </section>
```